# Why is this "not a statement" in java?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java.  My current program loops through a block that asks for users input in the console until the value they type equals done.  I want to store each value the user types in an array that is a class property.  When I try to append this array, I get an error that says `Error:(59, 18) java: not a statement`.  My code is below.  I will point out the line that the error occurs on inside the code.  Thanks for your time!

```
package com.example.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the musical key calculator!");
        System.out.println("Enter your notes one at a time.");
        System.out.println("Use uppercase letters A-G and # for sharp and b for flat.(Ex. Eb)");
        System.out.println("Remember that E# and B# do not exist in music!");
        System.out.println("When you have entered all of your notes, type 'done'");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");

        boolean finished = false;

        Scale YourScale = new Scale();
        while(finished == false) {

            System.out.print("Enter a note: ");

            String note = scanner.nextLine();

            if (note == "done'") {

                finished = true;

            } else {

                YourScale.addNote(note);

            }

        }

        if(finished == true){

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Your notes are ");
            String[] completedNotes = YourScale.notes;
            for (int i = 0; i < completedNotes.length; i++) {

                output.append(completedNotes[i] + " ");

            }

        }

    }

    public static class Scale {

        public String[] notes = {};

        public void addNote(String note){

            notes[] = note; //Error occurs here.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are fixed length, and that isn't how you create (or populate an array). I would prefer to use a `Collection` like,

```
public List<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
public void addNote(String note){
    notes.add(note);
}
```

But, you could use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) and something like

```
public String[] notes = new String[0];
public void addNote(String note){
    int len = notes.length;
    notes = Arrays.copyOf(notes, len + 1);
    notes[len] = note;
}
```

Finally, you do not test `String` equality with `==`

```
if (note == "done'") {
```

should be something like

```
if (note.equals("done")) {
```

Comment: +1 for `(note == "done")` I missed that, basically if you check strings this way it will always return false, as it tries to compare their address (like in C pointers).

Answer (score 1):

`notes` is a String array, which means it has many `String` objects inside. Also you initialize it to an empty array. Arrays should have a fixed size.

```
//Declare a variable notes, and initialize it as an empty array?
public String[] notes = {};

public void addNote(String note)
{
    //This doesn't make sense in java - it's syntax is wrong
    notes[] = note;
}
```

If you want to use arrays this is an example:

```
//Declare a variable notes, and initialize it as an array of 
//specific size (I used 5 as example)
public String[] notes = new String[5];

public void addNote(String note)
{
    //Here you should have some short of counter that counts in which
    // position of the array you will save 'note' or just run a 'for'
    //loop and the first element that is not initialized can get the note

    for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
        if (notes[i] == null)
        {
            notes[i] = note;
            break;
        }
}
```

Although this method allows you to save a fixed size, which is not desirable in your case, but nevertheless it uses `Array` and can help you understand how to use them.

If you want to implement it properly you should use an `ArrayList`. An `ArrayList` is an array where you can add new elements and remove them. You can find plenty of documentation online of how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to assign a String to a String array. You probably intended to add it to the array.